# Redirect not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, redirect

I moved a site from Joomla 2.5 -> 3.6 recently, and some of the URLs in the site changed.

For one critical URL I used the Joomla redirect manager to create a redirect, and it worked as expected.

However, within a few days the URL began to return 404 errors again. I checked it in the redirect manager, and it is still there, and still active. But it's not working.

Is there anything I can check to figure out why it was working then stopped?

Comment: If there are any parameters added to the URL, the Redirects component may not work properly for the URL. In that case, you would need to create additional redirects with the parameters included.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the URL is exactly the same as the one in the Redirect Manager? Also, remember that the Redirect Manager only works when the page returns the 404 error code - try to make sure that the page really returns 404 (and not 403 or other 4xx errors).

Final note: Are you sure that the plugin for the redirect manager is enabled?

Answer (score -1):

From my experience Redirect manager not work perfectly. I didn't get much time to inspect.

You can Use Sh404 extension(paid) or any 3rd party extension for this.

I prefer to handle this redirection from server level(nginx/apace).

For nginx follow this : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx

Apache : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx

Thanks

Comment: please elaborate more on your answer - why's and how's...

Comment: Updated my comment.